# Integrate WSO2 ESB 4.6.0 and BPS 3.0.0

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I am working with the latest releases of ESB and BPS, and would like to install them together (as opposed to installing them independently).  I have tried to install the ESB as a feature pack on the BPS, and vice versa, both using the Feature Management UI, but I can't seem to find either one in the repository.

Is there a repository that I'm missing, or a way to do this manually?

Answer (score 2):

You can use http://dist.wso2.org/p2/carbon/releases/4.0.2/ for BPS 3.0.0 features.

ESB 4.6.0 features will be based on http://dist.wso2.org/p2/carbon/releases/4.0.5/.